# No records returned in a query from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to query 3 tables in order to extract the average grade on all teachers

I have the following tables :

STUDENTS

```
create table students

(id int not null auto_increment,
    surname varchar(100) not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (id),
    unique(nume,prenume)
  );
```

TEACHERS

```
create table teachers(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    surname varchar(100) not null,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (id),
    unique(nume,prenume)
    );
```

CATALOG

```
create table catalog (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    `data` datetime not null,
    id_teacher int not null,
    id_student int not null,
    nota int not null,
    primary key (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_teacher) REFERENCES teachers(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_student) REFERENCES students(id)
  );
```

I need to make a query from which to result the students that have average degree >7.5 on all teachers.

I tried this but no result and I don't understand what is wrong :

```
select avg(c.nota) AS 'medie', c.id_student, e.surname, e.name, c.id_teacher, p.surname, p.name from catalog c
left join students e on e.id = c.id_student
left join teachers p on p.id = c.id_teacher
group by c.id_teacher
having avg(c.nota) > 7.5;
```

Comment: Have you got data in your tables? Can you report some data in your question?

Comment: 1 2013-09-04 07:47:20 1 1 4
2 2017-10-27 08:19:47 2 2 6
3 2017-02-10 12:53:34 3 3 7
4 2018-11-04 06:20:40 4 4 10
5 2014-12-26 08:12:38 5 5 9
6 2017-10-05 06:39:40 6 6 4
7 2016-03-14 06:28:56 7 7 7
8 2016-03-22 06:41:30 8 8 8
9 2013-10-06 11:16:33 9 9 10
This is data from Catalog - id / data / id_teacher/ id_student/ degree

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.  Your statement doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select s.id, avg(c.nota) medie
from catalog c
inner join students s on s.id = c.student_id
inner join teachers t on t.id = c.teacher_id
group by s.id, t.id
```

you get the ids of all the students with average > 7.5 for each teacher.
Then join to the `students` table:

```
select s.id, s.surname, s.name 
from students s inner join (
  select s.id, avg(c.nota) medie
  from catalog c
  inner join students s on s.id = c.student_id
  inner join teachers t on t.id = c.teacher_id
  group by s.id, t.id
) g  ON g.id_student = s.id
group by s.id, s.surname, s.name 
having min(g.medie) > 7.5
```

Comment: Thank you forpas for the answer. The requirment is to use 3 tables . One student can have multiple 'medie' on one teacher or all teachers. They need to have minumun >7.5 at all teachers .

Comment: *One student can have multiple 'medie' on one teacher or all teachers* meaning? Does every student have only 1 `nota` for a teacher?

Comment: the student has more then 1 'nota' for a teacher. And a student can have more 'nota' and be alocated to all teachers .

Comment: *the student has more 'nota' for a teacher* ok but what does this mean: *a student can have more 'nota' and be alocated to all teachers*?

Comment: # id_student, id_teacher, nota
       '9',              '9',            '10'
       '9',             '66',             '6'
       '9',              '67',             '9'
       '9',              '69',            '10'
for example the same student (id 9) has 4 teachers but he should not be returned in the query because he has 1 note of 6